# PHP - File Upload [POST]: Cannot process

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have an error when I try to upload an image / files. The image is uploaded but I have always this error.

```
[08-Sep-2016 09:45:29 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  File Upload [POST]: Cannot process $_FILES[products_image_resize]['tmp_name'] in /home/www/boutique/includes/OM/Upload.php on line 73
```

Line 73 o Upload class

```
if ( isset($_FILES[$this->_file]) ) {
        if ( isset($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']) && ($_FILES[$this->_file]['size'] > 0) ) {
          $this->_upload = array('type' => 'POST',
                                 'name' => $_FILES[$this->_file]['name'],
                                 'size' => $_FILES[$this->_file]['size'],
                                 'tmp_name' => $_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']);
        } else {
          trigger_error('File Upload [POST]: Cannot process $_FILES[' . $this->_file . '][\'tmp_name\']');
        }
      }
```

Inside my class products : function getImage()

```
// load originale image
      $image = new Upload('products_image_resize', DIR_FS_CATALOG_IMAGES  . $dir_products_image, null, array('gif', 'jpg', 'png'));

      if ( $image->check() && $image->save() ) {
        $error = false;
      }

      if ( $error === false ) {
        $sql_data_array['image'] = $dir_products_image . $separator . $image->getFilename();
      } else {
        $sql_data_array['image'] = '';
        $OSCOM_MessageStack->add(ERROR_CATALOG_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NOT_WRITEABLE, 'warning');
      }
```

called

```
// image
      $this->getImage();
```

In my html files, my form

```
<form name="new_product" action="http://boutique/admin/index.php?Products&cPath=&pID=3&action=update_product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My test

```
//print_r($_FILES[$this->_file]);
// Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) - no files
//Array ( [name] => shopping-bag.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpOg7mnD933577 [error] => 0 [size] => 933577 )  - files

print_r($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']); // 0 - no files
print_r($_FILES[$this->_file]['size']); // 0 - no file;

print_r($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']); // //tmp/phpOg7mnD933577 - files
print_r($_FILES[$this->_file]['size']); // /tmp/phpOg7mnD933577g - file;
```

line to test

```
if ( isset($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']) && ($_FILES[$this->_file]['size'] > 0) ) {
```

replaced by

```
if (!empty($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name'])) { // works
   if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name'])) { // File Upload [POST]: Cannot process $_FILES[products_image_resize]['tmp_name']
   if (($_FILES[$this->_file]['size'] > 0)) {  //works
```

Comment: $_FILES[$this->_file] instead of that $_FILES["$this->_file"] //try with double qoutes

Comment: Please also add a `print_r($_FILES[$this->_file])` here so we can see what's inside the `$_FILES` to easy debug.

Comment: Try logging your checks inside your `else`. `trigger_error('File Upload [POST]: Cannot process $_FILES[' . $this->_file . '][\'tmp_name\']: First: '.(isset($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']))." Second: ".(!empty($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name'])). " Third: ".(is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name']))." Fourth: ".(($_FILES[$this->_file]['size'] > 0)));`

Comment: That is **NOT** how you test for upload success. `if (isset($_FILES['foo']) && ($_FILES['foo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK))` is what you want. `tmp_name` can be still be set even if the upload failed

Comment: You should check for your specific error in `$_FILES['somefile']['error']`. Here's the manual page explaining the error codes: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: There the results :
//        if (!empty($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name'])) { // works

//       if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->_file]['tmp_name'])) { // File Upload [POST]: Cannot process $_FILES[products_image_resize]['tmp_name']

//         if (($_FILES[$this->_file]['size'] > 0)) {  //works

Answer (score 0):

In your form, change

```
<form name="new_product" action="http://boutique/admin/index.php?Products&cPath=&pID=3&action=update_product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form name="new_product" action="http://boutique/admin/index.php?Products&cPath=&pID=3&action=update_product" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```